# my world is changed when i loaded it

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-world

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi Dear All,

I create a world in Gazebo (Standalone Version 1.8) and I saved it, but when i load it, my world is changed?! any one know what is my fault?

for example i create this [world](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/13727438317418045.jpg) but when i load it i have this [world](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/13727438786897708.jpg), I've marked the changed part.

i loaded my world with this command:

```
>gazebo name_of_saved_world
```

and i save the world from file menu (save world as).

I've attached a world with a box. [test4.sdf](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/13735399117513992.sdf)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3401/my-world-is-changed-when-i-loaded-it/) by [Vahid](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/342/vahid/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 91 on 2013-07-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-07-01**:
Can you provide a few more details about your problem.

**Comment by [Vahid](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/342/vahid/) on 2013-07-02**:
Yes, I've added detail of my problem to main question, thank you so much for your consideration.

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-07-10**:
Can you add some code that shows the before and after differences? It will be hard for us to replicate the error just based on the images you attached. Thanks.

**Comment by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) on 2013-07-10**:
Model rotations don't get saved. To replicate: insert a box, rotate it, File -> Save World As. Load the saved world to see the model with zero rpy.

**Comment by [Vahid](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/342/vahid/) on 2013-07-11**:
Dear Scpeters, There is just one code ( a SDF File), for example i put a box in world and then rotate it and in final i save it, but when i load it, the box is in original form! I've attached this SDF file to main question, you can test it and see the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There are currently some problems with saving worlds. I've added yours to the existing ticket on the gazebo issue tracker:

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/563/fix-saving-worlds

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2013-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vahid](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/342/vahid/) on 2013-07-11**:
Thank you so much.